# Eclipse subversive on dev box issue

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive, file-sharing

I recently started on a new project where they do not have eclipse working with subversion. They say it is not possible because our dev boxes do not get internet connection. However, I'm not so quick to give up.

We are currently using TortoiseSVN over our secured network just fine. Surely we must be able to set-up Eclipse to do the same?

I have done some research and am having a hard time finding an answer off google searches and thought I'd ask here. Most of the SVN eclipse guides ive seen require a web address to host the file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try punching a local directory or a local server accessible to the machine(perhaps on the machine) that is/hosts a subversion repo into the box and see if it works.

Comment: Check your proxy config in eclipse, so make sure you have the correct SVN provider enabled for  your SVN config

Comment: How is it possible to do Java development without an Internet connection? What about Maven? Anyway, if you have TortoiseSVN working, you should be able to get the Subversion plugin in Eclipse working. Check to see if you need to setup a proxy.

Comment: thanks guys, this is helpful. Can anyone elaborate on setting up a proxy? In the past we had an issue with the authorizing eclipse to access the host file in tortoise.