# Virtual Box and With Subversion in Eclipse stopped working

Tags: eclipse, svn, virtualbox

I have been using Subversion in Eclipse inside my Debian Virtual Box for years but it now stopped working.

I had tried to upgrade eclipse and failed, but I rolled back to a previous snap shot. I even tried a copy I made of the box before the failed upgrade. I even tried rolling back to much earlier snapshot. Still the same issue.

I tried the methods here: [Eclipse subversive on dev box issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727878/eclipse-subversive-on-dev-box-issue)

No luck.

The only thing that has changed is I am at a new network now. But this network has worked before, I have been on this network many times. Also, the rest of eclipses connection features are working (such as egit).

I also have tried disconnecting and reconnecting my repos. No luck.

Further more svn works fine from the command line.

The Eclipse console also shows nothing, just empty while any svn process hangs.

I looked at the svn console in eclipse and I see it looks right:

svn update "[PATH]" -r HEAD --depth infinity

I tried that from command line and it works from there.

Subversion version info from installed software screen:
Revision Graph 0.7.9
SVN Connectors 2.2.2
SVN Integration For the Mylyn Project 0.7.9
SVN JDT Ignore Extensions 0.7.9
Team Provider 0.7.9
SVNKit 2.2.2

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

All the best.

Will Ferrer

Comment: You might want to describe how it's not working. What happens ? What do you do ?

Comment: Hi Nos. Thanks for the right back. Svn just hangs inside eclipse. The task is shown to be running (bottom right hand corner you can see the progress running.) but it never completes, it never even makes any progress in the task. It happens for all svn commands issued through eclipse: commits, updates, reverts, switches, anything. So in other words if I go to the team sub menu and select any action, the action never makes any progress, even if I leave it for an hour.

Comment: An update on this in case any one has any ideas. I am back to my phone network where this always worked for years, and it's still not working. This implies it didn't have to do with the new network I was on. Any advice would be appreciated.